# Rebinding a page in AngularDart when the data is loaded via SignalR

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've got an AngularDart application that is working, but I feel like I'm doing it wrong...

The application shows a list of events as they are received.  The events get to the app via SignalR, but I don't think that's really relevant - the issue is the way I'm having to update the component's state in order to see the changes in the state get displayed on the page.

Here is a cut down version of my component:

```dart
@Component( selector: 'liveEvents', templateUrl: 'live_events.html', useShadowDom: false )
class LiveEvents implements ScopeAware {
    VmTurnZone _vmTurnZone;
    EventReceiver _eventReceiver;
    LiveEvents( this._vmTurnZone, this._eventReceiver );
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    void _onEventReceived(Event event) {
        //TODO: This just does not seem right...
        _vmTurnZone.run(() => events.add(event));
    }

    void set scope(Scope scope) {
        var _events = _eventReceiver.subscribeToAllEvents( "localhost", _onEventReceived );
    }
}
```

The `EventReceiver` class is responsible for connecting to a SignalR server, receiving messages from that server and converting them into Event objects, and then calling whatever function was specified in the `subscribeToAllEvents` (in this case, `_onEventReceived`)

The angular template html is very simple:

```dart
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">Event: {{event.Id}}</li>
</ul>
```

This all works fine, but the bit I don't like is having to inject a `VmTurnZone` object into the component, and to have to update the events property from within a call to `run` on that `VmTurnZone`.  It just seems a bit overly complicated to me.  But if I DON'T do it in the `VmTurnZone.run` method, when the events property gets updated, the view is not updated to reflect that change.  Only from within `VmTurnZone.run` does it work.

Is there a simpler way to do what I'm after here?  I've looked at adding a watch to the scope, but that didn't seem to work (and looks to me like it should be used for changes that happen the other way around - ie, the view updates the scope, and you want to do something when that happens).

Can any AngularDart experts let me know if there's a better way to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Stream

You could add your events to stream and then listen for these and signalr will see these changes, for example:

```
@Component( selector: 'liveEvents', templateUrl: 'live_events.html', useShadowDom: false )
class LiveEvents implements ScopeAware {
    EventReceiver _eventReceiver;
    LiveEvents( this._eventReceiver );
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

    void set scope(Scope scope) {
        subscribe().listen((event){
            events.add(event);
        });
    }

    Stream<Event> subscribe(){
        var streamController = new StreamController<Event>();

        _eventReceiver.subscribeToAllEvents( "localhost", (event){
            streamController.add(event);
        });

        return streamController.stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for that - that's a much better way of doing it.  So does angular somehow know to watch the stream?

Comment: No problem, As far as I know because the stream was created in the current zone it knows about it so there for will react to new events that are added to stream.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is necessary when the source of the change is outside of the default Angular zone (for example some JavaScript library) for Angular to recognize model changes.

Comment: Thanks Günter.  It seems strange to me thought that Angular can't "watch" the events property for changes and update accordingly when that property is changed.  Is there perhaps some attribute that I can add to the property to tell Angular "Watch this property and include it in your list of things that cause rebinding when changed"?

Comment: You usually don't need this if the code runs in the same zone as Angular, but when it's some JavaScript code or some other code not invoked by the same `main()` method or for some other reason doesn't run in the same zone, `VmTurnZone` was introduced to allow change recognition anyway. I don't know SignalR and just assumed it is some JS library. I also don't have deep knowledge about this topic and maybe someone else knows a better answer.

Comment: Yep, you're right, SignalR is a JS library, so your assumptions are correct.  I guess I'll just live with it for now, but my concern is that a) I will forget why it is there in 6 months time and b) when some other developer comes along to work on the product they won't know what it's for, or may battle with the same hair pulling that we did before we discovered VmTurnZone.

Comment: Just add a link to this question in a comment above the `VmTurnZone` line :-)